# How to get initial binding with getx and flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, dart-null-safety

What is wrong with it? The analyzer says there is constant constructor, I do not understand it??

**The error**

[image: the error]

**The binding class**

[image: the binding class]

Comment: try remove the const word ...

Comment: there is no const word

Comment: return const GetMaterialApp()

Comment: thanks bro your the best